# Why doesn't my Qt Creator know QPolygon?

Tags: c++, qt, qpolygon

I have the following simple code. I just start writing my application and get stuck on this problem: Qt Creator tells me, that QPolygon file or directory doesn't exists. I checked it with QT Documentation and it says, ther is.

```
#include <QPolygon>

class IHledani
{
public:
    virtual IHledani();
    virtual ~IHledani();

    virtual QPolygon najdiKonturu(IObraz image, int startx, int starty);
};
```

Thank you

Comment: Is it just QPolygon that is the problem, or other Qt classes? If all classes, then check that your paths to Qt libraries are correct.

Comment: QPolygon is part of the QtGui module. Is he activated in your pro file ?

Comment: It maybe isnt, I created the project as Console app, can I activate it in this type off app ?

Comment: Add QT += gui in your .pro file, and remove the QT -= gui part. But this will mean your app will need the qtgui library.

Comment: `QPolygon` derives from `QVector<QPoint>` which is in the `QtCore` library, so do you need the extra functionality?